# Counting occurrences in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Lets say I want to count the total number of occurrences of a name contained within a string in a column and display that total next to all occurrences of that name in a new column beside it. For example, if I have:

```
Name  | Home Address | Special ID 
==================================
Frank | 152414       | aTRF342
Jane  | 4342342      | rRFC432
Mary  | 423432       | xTRF353
James | 32111111     | tLZQ399
May   |    4302443   | 3TRF322
```

How would I count the occurrences of special tags like 'TRF', 'RFC', or 'LZQ' so the table looks like this:

```
Name  | Home Address | Special ID  | Occurrences
================================================
Frank | 152414       | aTRF342     |     3
Jane  | 4342342      | rRFC432     |     1
Mary  | 423432       | xTRF353     |     3
James | 32111111     | tLZQ399     |     1
May   |    4302443   | 3TRF322     |     3
```

Currently using Access 2007. Is this even possible using a SQL query?

Comment: How do you know what the code is for a given row?  In the first example, it is the first 3 characters.  In the last, it is the last three characters.

Comment: edited to make the special tags appear in the same place, after the first character. So I could use substr like Josvic has suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Access 2007, I stored your sample data in a table named *tblUser1384831*.  The query below returns this result set.

```
Name  Home Address Special ID special_tag Occurrences
----  ------------ ---------- ----------- -----------
Frank 152414       aTRF342    TRF                   3
Jane  4342342      rRFC432    RFC                   1
Mary  423432       xTRF353    TRF                   3
James 32111111     tLZQ399    LZQ                   1
May   4302443      3TRF322    TRF                   3
```

Although your question has a vba tag, you don't need to use a VBA procedure for this.  You can do it with SQL and the `Mid()` function.

```
SELECT
    base.[Name],
    base.[Home Address],
    base.[Special ID],
    base.special_tag,
    tag_count.Occurrences
FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [Name],
                [Home Address],
                [Special ID],
                Mid([Special ID],2,3) AS special_tag
            FROM tblUser1384831
        ) AS base
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Mid([Special ID],2,3) AS special_tag,
                Count(*) AS Occurrences
            FROM tblUser1384831
            GROUP BY Mid([Special ID],2,3)
        ) AS tag_count
    ON base.special_tag = tag_count.special_tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to `GROUP BY` the substring of `Special ID`. In MS Access, you can read about how to compute substrings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809120/is-there-an-equivalent-to-the-substring-function-in-ms-access-sql).

The problem in your case is that your data in `Special ID` column does not follow a standard pattern, one which easy to extract via the `substring` function. You might need to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to extract such values, and later apply the `GROUP BY` to them.

With MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL you would be able to declare a stored procedure ([example CLR function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) in MS SQL Server) that would do this for you. Not sure with MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
select Name, [Home Address], [Special ID], 
       (select count(*) from [your table] where [Special ID] = RemoveNonAlphaCharacters([Special ID]) ) as Occurrences
from [your table]
```

auxiliar function (got from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)):

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    While PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say your first table is called 'table_with_string'

the following code will show the occurance based on the first 3 charecters of string in Special ID column. since it is not clear how exactly you are passing the string to match

```
select tws.Name,tws.HomeAddress,tws.SpecialID,str_count.Occurrences from    
table_with_string tws
left join
(select SpecialID,count(*) from table_with_string where specialID like(substring  
(specialid,0,3))
group by specialId) as str_count(id,Occurrences)
on str_count.id=tws.SpecialID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this explicitly as a join, so you are clear on how it works:

```
select tws.Name, tws.HomeAddress, tws.SpecialID, str_count.Occurrences
from table_with_string tws 
join
(
  select substring(spcecialid, 2, 3) as code, count(*) as Occurrences
  from table_with_string tws
  group by substring(spcecialid, 2, 3)
) s
  on s.code = substring(tws.spcecialid, 2, 3)
```